# What stickers are available to hide the glowing Apple logo on the back of my MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro, accessories

I would like to hide the glowing Apple logo on the backside of my MacBook Pro.

I'm looking for a simple silver colored sticker. And I don't want to add any message or other brand or art on my laptop.

Is there any unobtrusive sticker available?

Comment: The logo is easily covered by whatever 3" round vinyl sticker you choose.

Comment: @bmike where do I get an unobtrusive silver colored (aluminum) sticker?

Comment: If you don't have a local shop that will print them, there's always the googles. http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=custom+vinyl+sticker&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: Since this is a hardware recommendation and isn't about using your Apple product, [it's off topic](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/refining-policy-on-hardware-recommendations). Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Any sticker will be obtrusive it's is aim is to just mask the Apple logo.  Without you get something to cover the whole rear panel your sticker be as obvious as the logo it's trying to replace, and will probably look a lot worse as there will be some light bleeding through the vinyl unless it's a serious thick sticker, which will then catch on things and have edge-peel issues etc.

Search on Amazon for Macbook and Gelaskins for an idea for covering the whole rear, this is an example:
[image]

If you want something smaller, you can use something to take the edge off it by highlighting it in a way that marginally masks it:

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for a simple silver colored sticker. And I don't want to add any message or other brand or art on my laptop.

Comment: What are you trying to remove, the sheer "apple-ness" of it, or just the glow?  For instance would a plain apple sticker of identical dimensions used to blackout the backlight be good?  If you want silver, then having subtle might be hard, as it's liable to clash horribly with the aluminium colour/texture unless you are lucky

Comment: I want to remove sheer "apple-ness". And I'm looking already for a long time for a solution unluckily.

Comment: If you do this, I think Steve will haunt you.

Comment: @powtac - on the same note: have you considered a case for your MBP? Like: http://www.amazon.com/Premium-Quality-Leather-SmackTom-Packaging/dp/B004BE6LMW

Comment: As I said before, I just want to get rid of the Apple logo but not of the original sleek design of the MBP. And "no", I do not look for a fancy sticker or hull or any other type of case.